# AngularJS modularity and configuration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module, angularjs-config

I have a feature that has controllers, services, and templates in it which I want to use in two separate projects. I've put template and controller names into a `constant` so I can change if I need. It works almost perfect.

However, in a view, I need to get options of a ui-select differently in these projects. It will be an array from `$rootScope` in both of them but comes from different variables. I think I cannot use `constant`, so what can I use?

Comment: So, where's the question?

Comment: Updated it. Is it clear now?

Comment: Why not either write a service that reads from the different variables but spits out an array in both cases? This service would be different for the two projects, but its customers only need this service s a dependency. Alternatively, use `$emit` or `$broadcast` to broadcast data to the controller feeding the ui-select.